# Simple search on masterpage and display results on a different page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm still a beginner at ASP.NET and C#. In my current project, I have to do a "simple search".

My search bar is on the master page and I want the results of the search to be displayed on `Searchside.aspx`. I just want to be able to search on `slips_navn` (tie_name) in my database.

This is what I currently have and I don't know how to move on from here.

**MasterPage button / textbox**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="SearchTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="ButtonSearch" runat="server" Text="Søg" OnClick="ButtonSearch_Click" />
```

**Code behind Master page**

```
protected void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Response.Redirect("~/searchside.aspx?SearchText=" + SearchTextBox.Text);   

}
```

**Searchside.aspx**

And this is where i want to display the results.

```
 <div id="randomslips">
     <b><%#Eval("maerke_navn") %></b>
     <p><%#Eval("slips_navn") %></p>
     <img alt="" src='prod_image2/<%# Eval("billede") %> ' height="100px" width="100px" />
     <b>DKK<%#Eval("slips_pris") %>,-</b>
     <a class="Infoknap" href='EnkeltSlips.aspx?id=<%#Eval("Slips_id") %>'>INFO</a>
 </div>
```

**My Tie table.**(slips)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[slips] (
    [slips_id]    INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [slips_tekst] NVARCHAR (MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [slips_pris]  DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [billede]     NVARCHAR (MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [slips_navn]  NVARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [FK_maerke]    INT             NOT NULL,
    [status]      INT             NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([slips_id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Slips_maerke] FOREIGN KEY ([FK_maerke]) REFERENCES [dbo].[maerke] ([maerke_id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Maerke table (Brand)

```
( 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[maerke] (
    [maerke_id]   INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [maerke_navn] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([maerke_id] ASC)
);
```

So thus far, when i press the Search button on master page, i get redirected to **searchside.aspx?SearchText=blue** as it should, but i dont know how i should connect to the database, via codebehind and how? or via sql-datasource / repeater and how?. i included the 2 database tables i expect to search from, i again, want to search on **tie_name ( slips_navn )** Row. i apologies if im still not being clear, and i will try to update my question again untill hopefully i can explain what i want answered :)

Comment: So what is the problem? If you redirect to the search-page and pass the search-parameter as query-string you can read that parameter on the search-page.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Can you show how to do that? currently when i press the Search button it redirects to the searchside.aspx as i should, and also adds the textfield input to the query string " searchside.aspx?SearchText=blue " etc. and then shows the box where i want the ties to be displayed, but with no data, so my question is, how do i, i guess connect to the database from here? a sql datasource? code behind? if you could give me a visual it would be great.

Comment: it's not clear where you've got stuck. If this question is just about sql you should remove all the ASP.NET stuff since it's misleading. If you don't know how to diplay the result: use server-controls like `Panel`(for div) and a `Label` to set it's `Text`-property according to the search result. Or maybe you want to list multiple, then use a `ListBox` or even a `GridView`. But don't ask multiple questions in one. Btw, if it's a sql-issue you should provide more informations about the data model.

Comment: yeah im sorry if im not being clear, but it's an SQL issue then. all the code i have shown is working and i'm not sure how to do the rest, im not sure if the SQL should be on the masterPage or searchside.aspx etc, and how to write it for that matter. and i usually display data via Eval(s) so thats what came to mind. if im still not being clear i will try to edit the question. but agaim im still quite new and bad at asking questions about this subject.

Comment: Just query your database in a method of `Searchside.aspx`. This method gets called from it's `Page_Load` event if `Request.QueryString["SearchText"] != null`. Then set the `Label`'s `Text` property from that method or use the result of your database query to fill a `DataTable`(or other collection like `List<T>`) which can be used as `DataSource` of a web-databound control like `DataList`,`Repeater` or `GridView` and call `grid.DataBind`. So if the result is a single value i would set a `Label`'s `Text` and if it yields multiple values use another control (`ListBox` is another simple option).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh well figured it out, and it was actually pretty easy. I guess my brain just couldent figure it out on friday. Here is my result.

**i still use the**

```
Response.Redirect("~/searchside.aspx?SearchText=" + SearchTextBox.Text);
```

and this is on **searchside.aspx**. i have no code on **`sarchside.cs`**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3">
        <ItemTemplate>
       <div id="randomslips">
                <b><%#Eval("maerke_navn") %></b>
             <p><%#Eval("slips_navn") %></p>
             <img alt="" src='prod_image2/<%# Eval("billede") %> ' height="100px" width="100px" />
             <b>DKK<%#Eval("slips_pris") %>,-</b>
             <a class="Infoknap" href='EnkeltSlips.aspx?id=<%#Eval("Slips_id") %>'>INFO</a>

        </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [slips] INNER JOIN maerke ON slips.FK_mærke = maerke.maerke_id WHERE ([slips_navn] LIKE '%' + @slips_navn + '%')"><SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter QueryStringField="SearchText" Name="slips_navn" Type="String"></asp:QueryStringParameter>
    </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

so as you can see i just used a repeater and sql-datasource and got the querystringfield via a querystring parameter.

Answer (score 0):

first of all use gridview or datalist to bind data in Searchside.aspx
after that in page load event of Searchside.aspx check query string that you past for seraching.

If u found query string in page load than bind that datalist or grindview according to new searched dataset.

Comment: Thank you, but for some reason i cant atall get a view in my head on how to continue, if you could show me an example it would be great.